# Is there a way to check if a file is an SQLite3 DB?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am writing a simple C program to check if a File F is a usable SQLite3 database.

I tried writing gibberish into a file `test.db`, but `sqlite3_open("test.db", &db)` returned 0.

I suppose either `sqlite3_status()` or `sqlite3_db_status()` do what I want, but the documentation states something different.

Comment: What are your requirements? is checking the header enough? Or do you want to analyse the database for defects?

Comment: I just want to know if F is an actual SQLite DB or an unuseable file (e.g text file, random file, etc.)

Comment: Which part of the documentation states what differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [thread](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sqlite3-open-on-non-DB-file-td43197.html).

It looks like `sqlite3_open` will return SQLITE_OK even if the file is not a database.  However, when you try execute a statement you will get SQLITE_NOTADB.  Instead of reading the header, you could just do something like `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` after opening the database and check if SQLITE_NOTADB is returned.  You could go a step further and use the data returned to make sure all your tables exists.

Answer (score 1):

[the file must begin with a fixed header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html).  if you want to recognise valid files, that should be fine.

Comment: So there is no thing like `sqlite3_db_isvalid()`?